# Creating a heatmap from vector grid and point layer with QGIS

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I would like to make a heatmap based on the number of hits within a certain area.

1. I begin by importing the data of my hits:
   Layers > add layer > add delimited text layer = ok
2. I add google satellite layer = ok
3. I add a raster:
   Vector > analysis tools > vector-grid > Select area from map > X=10, Y=10 > grid as polygon
4. Vector > analysis tools > count points in polygon
5. Open attribute tabel = I get my dimensions X min/max and Y min/max + number of points

Now I would like to make a heatmap where each square gets separate color. I think I need to use the data from the atttribute table but I don't know how.
I would like to obtain the result below

Example: each square with hits between 10-15 hits = red, 5-9 hits = orange, 1-4 hits = green.

Can this be done and if yes, how?

Comment: You should add tags and change your title to something that relates to your question like "Heatmap based on the number of hits within an area"..

Comment: If you have a vector grid that has an attribute table containing the number of points in then it should be a simple case of going into the feature properties > Style > Select Graduated > Select number of points in polygon for Column > Then classify and amend your classes to the ranges above.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and accurate response. It works exactly like i wanted!

Comment: @AGW94 it looks like you should write your comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your vector grid with the attribute table containing the field with the number of points in, right click on your layer in the layers panel and select "*Properties*".

Select "*Style*" from the left hand panel and select "*Graduated*" from the drop down menu at the top.

Select your column header as the number of points field in the "*Column*" drop down.

Then choose an appropriate colour scheme from the "*Color ramp*" drop down and click "*Classify*".

You can then amend the ranges by double clicking on them under the "*Values*" heading.

Finish by clicking "*OK*"